# How to add gzip in Kong 0.13 for a proxy route?

Tags: gzip, kong

I am trying to enable gzip in Kong proxy for a route, So I added a header Content-Encoding:gzip using the kong response transformer plugin ; which does not work, as I don't see gzip in the response. How to add gzip on route level when frontend client (served by a s3 bucket) is proxied via kong?

Answer (score 0):

to configure gzip in kong you shoud add this configuration below to nginx.conf

```
server {
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256; # default value 1000 ~ 20byte
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
}
```